# how to make drawer in another vue file visible on click synchronizely

Tags: vue.js

new in vue js.. i have a vue app which when click on the table data it will showing drawer by usng ant-design drawer. it is working when drawer code and is in one file. but i need it to be seperated.i have import the new file that added with drawer code and the drawer is not working on click the data. how can i sync both vue file?

i have tried `:visible.sync` but i do not know how this thing function. is there any reference that i could refer on or any documentation about `.sync`

Answer (score 0):

am not sure  how you want your file structure to be, but if drawer file is child of the table , you can emit an event from the parent and listen to it in the child by using

```
`this.$parent.$on('event_name', ()=> doSomething())`
```

or just emit an public event from the parent 
`this.$root.$emit('event_name')`

and then listen to it `this.$root.$on('event_name',()=> dosomething)`